# PC Doesn't Boot Windows after CPU Upgrade

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios, intel-core-i9

My PC has Intel Core i5 9600k and AORUS Z390 Pro Wifi Motherboard, I decided to buy Core i9 9900K since I started to need it, So I Installed the CPU added the thermal paste and the Cooler is Kraken X62, My PC should the Aorus Logo and then froze ! So I checked with BIOS found the CPU i9 showing in the BIOS, So I made sure I have the Win 10's SSD selected in the Boot menu, but keeps freezing on the Arous Screen , some time shows the Aorus logo and saying Preparing repair, but also freezes there, So I thought maybe the Windows got messed up or something, So I tried to re install windows by inserting the Windows 10 USB Drive, And selected it as boot drive, also showed up Windows Logo then froze as well ! tried to make my own Windows 10 bootable USB Drive and same issue, So I thought maybe its the New CPU, so I re installed my Core i5 and the PC booted normally and the windows and everything still the same !?

So my question here : Is the new CPU Core i9 9900k Is defective for example ? or I'm I missing something here ?

Because even if its the windows, I can't even boot to the windows 10 installation.

And is it possible that my Motherboard shows the i9 installed and shows its clock speed but its defective for example ?

Because as far as I know my build is compatible with the new Processor.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disconnect all drives and let it boot to BIOS (UEFI Firmware). Make sure that UEFI setup does not freeze and is completely accessible and working. Then check if there’s a latest firmware (BIOS) update for your board and try updating it and after BIOS update re-check clean installation of Windows 10 again. In BIOS (UEFI) if there's an option to load optimized defaults try those settings first.

Comment: Patkim is correct about your BIOS, I just read your specs, Great Motherboard! 2019 BIOS __Fix CPU Vcore and power behavior__; Workaround beta BIOS to improve Kingston DDR4-2666 stability concern on some specific memory chip suppliers.

Comment: @patkim thanks, I think I need to update my BiOS, I have F8 when I downloaded F12C BIOS from the motherboard webpage it showed 3 files, autoexec.bat & Efiflash.exe & Z390AOPW.12c    ... is it the 12c extension is the BIOS or ?

Comment: @Hussein Elbeheiry If you can, boot the computer, if you cannot get to Windows, open a command prompt from a boot disk (you may need to copy them to the USB drive which you are booting from), and type __Efiflash.exe Z390AOPW.12c__ this should flash the BIOS. In the Readme.txt file with the IFIFlash, you have other options __/S - Save Original BIOS Image to Disk__. Your motherboard already has a backup of the original BIOS, there is an option to FLASH both, I would not recommend this because something may go wrong while flashing.  _P.S._ I don't think patkim is online at this time.

Comment: It was indeed the BIOS, I updated from F8 to F11 and the i9 worked fine without any issues or Clean windows install  Add it as an answer, @patkim

Comment: I have added the answer. Thank you to @vssher for their comments on how to proceed with BIOS update when I was offline.

Comment: have you updated intel chipset drivers? its what helps hardware communicate to the os

Comment: @user1252556 I have already marked the answer to my question as shown below, and it was the BIOS not the chipset drivers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As confirmed by the user, BIOS (UEFI Firmware update) fixed the issue.

In case your Windows 10 install hangs or freezes at Windows logo then do check what is the current BIOS (Firmware) revision on your Motherboard and if the vendor has released any latest firmware taking care of any previously known issues that may help detect and work with high end CPUs or specific memory models or any other hardware interface.

Freeze at Windows 10 logo could mean some sort of hardware incompatibility or driver issue many a times and one try is to check and update the Firmware and see if the issue resolves.

Sometimes one can even try installing only one piece of hardware e.g. only one RAM at a time, only one SSD/HDD at a time etc to check if any other hardware as well is causing the hang.

In this case user updated the Firmware to the revision F11 (From earlier F8 which was quite old)  and as reported by the user, he was able to proceed with clean install of Windows 10 without any further issues.

In the Firmware setup, unless absolutely necessary like enabling CPU Virtualization or trying some overclocking settings, it's suggested to leave the settings at Optimized Defaults.